# merge php arrey on action url get request

Tags: php, loops, http, get, get-request

I have an IP phone that through 2 action urls makes a get request to my web server.

action urls:

```
http://192.168.25.126/action.php?ID=$call_id&remote=$display_remote
http://192.168.25.126/action.php?ID=$call_id&extension=$active_user
```

`192.168.25.126` is the web server

`action.php` is printing to a log file the request

`$call_id` is a unique ID that the phone is giving to the current session

`$remote` is the caller's number

`$extension` is the ip phone extension number

on the server side I have the `action.php` that prints in a log file the requests through this simple line

```
 <?php
 file_put_contents("/tmp/post.log",print_r($_GET,true), FILE_APPEND));
 ?>
```

checking the log I can view the expected request

```
tail -f /tmp/post.log
Array
(
    [ID] => 9
    [remote] => +39123456789
)
Array
(
    [ID] => 9
    [extension] => 235
)
```

How can I merge in tmp.log the arreys with same ID like this?

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 9
    [remote] => +39123456789        
    [extension] => 235
)
```

**pay attention that the first arrey is generated on the ringing event and the second arrey is generated when I pickup the phone(or better to say when a call in enstablished)so in a second moment**
I cannot do this with only one action url like this

```
http://192.168.25.126/action.php?ID=$call_id&remote=$display_remote&extension=$active_user
```

due a limitation of my ip phone so I have to merge the 2 arreys. and if possible I would like,but this is not really necessary, that the log is printed only if the first arrey with same ID exist(so the log will appears only if an incoming call is answered and not when I make a call).
I'm a senior IT not a php coder so just want a suggestion to write the loop.. many thanks

Comment: Is it only those 2 arrays? Then `array_merge($firstArray, $secondArray);` would do.

Comment: thank you but this is not so easy..I think that I have to write a foreach relation..

Comment: _sidenote:_ I'd suggest to write either a `json_encode($_GET)` or at least a `serialize($_GET)` to the log, because you'd never could read that data again, as php cannot parse the output of print_r (natively)

Comment: So, just for my understanding: In the log shall be many arrays with different IDs or only those two? And you want to merge them _after_ (at least the first one) they were written to the log? Basicly appending the second one, right?

Comment: I want in the log only the merged arreys, a merged arrey for each inbound call that I pickup

Comment: Each new call has a new ID?

Comment: yes id is starting from id=1 and incrementing but after I think 5 minutes of phone idle it will reset again to id=1. 
in reality it would be enough for me to have only the last merged arrey in the log. this is for my crm developer that needs to grab this log for a inbound call popup. the crm is really customized and is not capable with the api of my asterisk implementation and action urls are the only way to grab the extension that answered the call. so the last merged arrey will be enough

Answer (score 1):

From what I'm understanding this should do what you need - expecting IDs to be unique.

```
<?php
// get data from log
$fileData = file_get_contents("/tmp/post.log");
$data = json_decode($fileData, true);  // make an array out of the json
// $data will now be something like this:
# $data = [["ID" => 9,"remote" => "+39123456789"],["ID" => 10,"remote" => "+41123456789"]];

// mocking input data
# $_GET = ['ID' => 10, 'otherparam' => 'bar'];

$key = array_search($_GET['ID'], array_column($data, 'ID')); // search for pre-saved data
if($key) {   // an item with $ID was found -> merge new data
    $item = array_merge($data[$key], $_GET);
    $data[$key] = $item;  // overwrite existing item with this ID
} else {
    $item = $_GET;  // create a new item, since we haven't found one
    $data[] = $item; // append to data

}
file_put_contents("/tmp/post.log",json_encode($data,true))); // don't append, write the whole dataset
```

If the IDs are not unique, we could just grab the last added one (via end(), check if IDs match and merge there:

```
end($data); // set pointer to the end
$key = key($data); // get the key of the last element
if($data[$key]['ID']==$_GET['ID']) {
    $item = array_merge($data[$key], $_GET); // merge old and new data
    $data[$key] = $item; // overwrite item
}
```

*EDIT:*
If you only need the last call, we don't need to re-save the non-matching arrays, so this adapted code should do:

```
<?php
$fileData = file_get_contents("/tmp/post.log");
$data = json_decode($fileData, true);
// $data will now be something like this:
# $data = ["ID" => 9,"remote" => "+39123456789"]; // note, this time it's a one-dimentional (but assoc) array.
// mocking input data
# $_GET = ['ID' => 9, 'otherparam' => 'bar'];

// check if we have pre-saved data, that has an 'ID' and that matches our current one:
if(is_array($data) && isset($data['ID']) && $data['ID']==$_GET['ID']) {   // the saved $ID was found -> merge new data
    $data = array_merge($data, $_GET);
} else {
    $data = $_GET;  // create a new item, since we haven't found one
}
file_put_contents("/tmp/post.log",json_encode($data,true))); // don't append, write the whole dataset
```

*Disclaimer:* This code has no error checking whatsoever and will throw errors on a blank log (because json_decode will fail if there's no data yet), has some security issues (using $*GET without sanitizing and writing that to a file...), doesn't test for proper input (what if no ID is sent), etc...*

Comment: thank you so much unfortunately I'm writing from italy and here is 2am I will try tomorrow your code and I will report the result, at least I have a starting point..

Comment: Don't you need the true/1 flag in the json decode function to get an array instead of object? I thought array search/column would fail on an object

Comment: @TCooper You are abolutely correct, I changed it, thanks!

Comment: ok I tried the code with unique ID and what I got is this:
an incoming call is ringing on the extensions my log is 
    [{"ID":"4","remote":"+39123456789"} then I pickup the call and the log becomes [{"ID":"4","remote":"+39123456789"},{"ID":"4","extension":"235"}]
 this is not an arrey...

Comment: I forgot to mention that there was an error on the last line and I removed a parenthesis that excees

Comment: In my code I still had a hardcoded (test-) ID here: `array_search('10',`, it of course has to be `array_search($_GET['ID'],`. Did you change that already?

Comment: what I need is a separate log, let's say arrey.log, where is present only the last merged arrey in the moment that is merged, cause the crm needs to read only the merged arrey in the istant that is merged, your code works but the log show in the first moment the incoming call and then will show the merged arrey.

Comment: You did change (=remove) the last param in `file_put_contents()`? - the  `FILE_APPEND` should not be there anymore.